# How to do bitwise operation decently?

Tags: matlab, bit-manipulation, octave

I'm doing analysis on binary data. Suppose I have two uint8 data values:

```
a = uint8(0xAB);
b = uint8(0xCD);
```

I want to take the lower two bits from `a`, and whole content from `b`, to make a 10 bit value. In C-style, it should be like:

```
(a[2:1] << 8) | b
```

I tried `bitget`:

```
bitget(a,2:-1:1)
```

But this just gave me separate `[1, 1]` logical type values, which is not a scalar, and cannot be used in the `bitshift` operation later.

My current solution is:

1. Make `a|b` (`a` or `b`):

   `temp1 = bitor(bitshift(uint16(a), 8), uint16(b));`
2. Left shift six bits to get rid of the higher six bits from `a`:

   `temp2 = bitshift(temp1, 6);`
3. Right shift six bits to get rid of lower zeros from the previous result:

   `temp3 = bitshift(temp2, -6);`

Putting all these on one line:

```
result = bitshift(bitshift(bitor(bitshift(uint16(a), 8), uint16(b)), 6), -6);
```

This is doesn't seem efficient, right? I only want to get `(a[2:1] << 8) | b`, and it takes a long expression to get the value.

Please let me know if there's well-known solution for this problem.

Comment: It may be worth flagging that if you're handling "big data", you will get much better performance by writing a short mex file to do the bit twiddling. Matlab's bit*() operators are convenience functions, and are not high performance. It's common practice to write a C mex to perform one aspect of a task that Matlab does not handle well but C does (such as this). If the data set is tiny, no need to bother, and the in-Matlab approach is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `or` is equivalent to an addition when dealing with integers

```
result = bitshift(bi2de(bitget(a,1:2)),8) + b;
```

e.g

```
a = 01010111
b = 10010010

result =       00000011            100010010
       = a[2]*2^9 + a[1]*2^8   +       b
```

an alternative method could be

```
result = mod(a,2^x)*2^y + b;
```

where the `x` is the number of bits you want to extract from `a` and `y` is the number of bits of `a` and `b`, in your case:

```
result = mod(a,4)*256 + b;
```

an extra alternative solution close to the `C` solution:

```
result = bitor(bitshift(bitand(a,3), 8), b);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is really inspiring, and decent, my workaround is dumb, I will modify it to your proposal.

Comment: Thanks to horchler's kind modification as well.

Comment: @fiddle, if you find my answer correct, please accept it (ticket besides the answer)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Octave, you can make use of `bitpack` and `bitunpack`:

```
octave> a = bitunpack (uint8 (0xAB))
a =

   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   1

octave> B = bitunpack (uint8 (0xCD))
B =

   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1
```

Once you have them in this form, it's dead easy to do what you want:

```
octave> [B A(1:2)]
ans =

   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1
```

Then simply pad with zeros accordingly and pack it back into an integer:

```
octave> postpad ([B A(1:2)], 16, false)
ans =

   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0

octave> bitpack (ans, "uint16")
ans = 973
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is important to explain exactly what "(a[2:1] << 8) | b" is doing.

In assembly, referencing individual bits is a single operation. Assume all operations take the exact same time and "efficient" a[2:1] starts looking extremely inefficient.

The convenience statement actually does (a & 0x03).

If your compiler actually converts a uint8 to a uint16 based on how much it was shifted, this is not a 'free' operation, per se. Effectively, what your compiler will do is first clear the "memory" to the size of uint16 and then copy "a" into the location. This requires an extra step (clearing the "memory" (register)) that wouldn't normally be needed.

This means your statement actually is (uint16(a & 0x03) << 8) | uint16(b)

Now yes, because you're doing a power of two shift, you could just move a into AH, move b into AL, and AH by 0x03 and move it all out but that's a compiler optimization and not what your C code said to do.

The point is that directly translating that statement into matlab yields

bitor(bitshift(uint16(bitand(a,3)),8),uint16(b))

But, it should be noted that while it is not as TERSE as (a[2:1] << 8) | b, the number of "high level operations" is the same.

Note that all scripting languages are going to be very slow upon initiating each instruction, but will complete said instruction rapidly. The terse nature of Python isn't because "terse is better" but to create simple structures that the language can recognize so it can easily go into vectorized operations mode and start executing code very quickly.

The point here is that you have an "overhead" cost for calling bitand; but when operating on an array it will use SSE and that "overhead" is only paid once. The JIT (just in time) compiler, which optimizes script languages by reducing overhead calls and creating temporary machine code for currently executing sections of code MAY be able to recognize that the type checks for a chain of bitwise operations need only occur on the initial inputs, hence further reducing runtime.

Very high level languages are quite different (and frustrating) from high level languages such as C. You are giving up a large amount of control over code execution for ease of code production; whether matlab actually has implemented uint8 or if it is actually using a double and truncating it, you do not know. A bitwise operation on a native uint8 is extremely fast, but to convert from float to uint8, perform bitwise operation, and convert back is slow. (Historically, Matlab used doubles for everything and only rounded according to what 'type' you specified)

Even now, octave 4.0.3 has a compiled bitshift function that, for bitshift(ones('uint32'),-32) results in it wrapping back to 1. BRILLIANT! VHLL place you at the mercy of the language, it isn't about how terse or how verbose you write the code, it's how the blasted language decides to interpret it and execute machine level code. So instead of shifting, uint32(floor(ones / (2^32))) is actually FASTER and more accurate.

Comment: can you please narrow down your answer?